# VK Mini app get error. Error: 5: User authorization failed: invalid session

Tags: vk

I use  @vkontakte/vk-miniapps-deploy and VK Mini app get error after `npm run deploy`.

```
Error: 5: User authorization failed: invalid session.
Error: "upload_url is undefined"
```

Answer (score 2):

Just run

`rm ~/.config/configstore/@vkontakte/vk-miniapps-deploy.json`